# Laravel Task Scheduling not running all commands

Tags: php, laravel

In my dev environment, I'm using Laravel Homestead. I have a bunch of commands that I ran regularly with [Laravel's task scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling).

**Kernel.php**:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('disposable:update')->weekly();
    $schedule->command('command:randomusercreatesubmission')->withoutOverlapping()->everyTenMinutes();
    $schedule->command('command:randomusercreatecomment')->withoutOverlapping()->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('command:randomusercreatereply')->withoutOverlapping()->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('command:randomusersubmissionvote')->withoutOverlapping()->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('command:randomusercommentvote')->withoutOverlapping()->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('command:randomusersubscribe')->withoutOverlapping()->everyFiveMinutes();

    $schedule->command(CalculateHotness::class)
        ->runInBackground()
        ->withoutOverlapping()
        ->everyFiveMinutes();

    $schedule->command(CalculateRelativeHotness::class)
        ->runInBackground()
        ->withoutOverlapping()
        ->everyFiveMinutes();
```

but recently I noticed that some of these scheduled commands aren't running. So I decided to `Log` whenever a command was run. Turns out, only `command:randomusercreatecomment` and `command:randomusercreatesubmission` are being run on schedule. I figured that maybe the next command (command:randomusersubmissionvote) was causing the issue. But when I SSH into homestead and run the command, it runs just fine and logs. I've tried to halt/up vagrant, I rebooted my PC, etc. There's no error log so I don't really understand why all the other commands aren't running.

Comment: Maybe you can to Logging from crontab to find out what command wasn't run properly. Please try something like this in crontab -e
* * * * * cd ~/projects/statistics && php ~/projects/statistics/artisan schedule:run >> cron-log.txt 2>&1
and you get output like 
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.4' 'artisan' get_green_count > '/dev/null' 2>&1
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.4' 'artisan' get_tv_statistics > '/dev/null' 2>&1
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.4' 'artisan' get_green_count > '/dev/null' 2>&1

Comment: I figured out my problem. All the commands had "withoutOverlapping()". I didn't know that that meant no other commands could run at the same time. So if I have 3 commands that run every 5 minutes, only 1 of them will run with "withoutOverlapping()", I guess? That's kinda dumb.

Comment: I think this is only related for the specific command not for all of them. So you run command 1 but it's not completed after 1 minute this command should be executed again but it won't until the first is completed. Please check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps